# mySQL JOIN columns and count distinct on one table and get more values on other table

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a db to organize my movies. I have two tables (1 for movies one for actors). Putting it simple and omitting useless fields for this exercise

```
Table MOVIE: 
    id_movie | name_movie | star1 | star2 | star3 | runtime

Table ACTOR: 
    id_actor | name | sex | image
```

There are movies where the star1 is for example "Morgan Freeman" but on other movies "Morgan Freeman" is in the field star2.

I wanna count `DISTINCT` values from the `UNION` of star1, star2, star3 from the table MOVIE and then go get the actor/actress sex and image on the table ACTOR.

Already tried all different kinds of queries but no results so far :(

Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

@Tom Green's solution is very close... except needing the "DISTINCT" in his query.

However, distinct actors, you already have an actor table, query from that directly, that SHOULD be unique of actors and actresses regardless of the movie they were featured in.

However, if you wanted to know distinct actor/actresses who were in the same MOVIE as someone else, I would actually adjust your database structure to a more flexible structure allowing as many "stars" as you need by using a "bridge" or "link" table... offering 1:many relationship

```
Table MOVIE: 
    id_movie | name_movie | star1 | star2 | star3 | runtime


Table MovieActor:
    id_movieactor  | id_movie | id_actor (star)

Table ACTOR: 
    id_actor | name | sex | image
```

to populate the MovieActor table here, you could...

```
insert into MovieActor ( id_movie, id_actor )
   select id_movie, star1 as id_actor
      from movie
      where star1 > 0
   union
   select id_movie, star2 as id_actor
      from movie
      where star2 > 0
   union
   select id_movie, star3 as id_actor
      from movie
      where star3 > 0
```

This way, you are unlimited in number of stars per movie, yet can have a minimum of 1 without wasted space of the others... Then, in the future, you want to adjust your queries by adding a possible 4th star to movies, how many queries will you be adjusting...

Anyhow, once this is done, you can query as simple as

```
select distinct ma.id_actor, actor.*
   from MovieActor ma join Actor on ma.id_actor = actor.id_actor
```

If you had some other examples of types of queries you might be posing to get out of your database, I could easily offer supplemental queries...

Comment: @Tom Green and @DRapp: Thanks for your prompt reply guys! Never imagine I'd get answers so fast!! I know the structure of my DB wasn't the best so I'm taking this opportunity to do how you guys tell me and build that 3rd MovieActor for more flexibility. I know it was a little flaw to only allow 3 actors, but it was a number I thought it would simplify things. @DRapp: tried to populate the new table with that query and got 0 rows inserted :| Also: My original idea was showing a top10 of movies per actor or actress... how would I do that with the new table in place? Anyway... THANKS A LOT! :)

Comment: @Afonso Gomes,  I just created the 3 tables structures and ran the insert... it failed... then I remembered... I needed to make the "id_MovieActor" as an "auto-increment" column... THEN it worked.  As for top 10 movies, what constitutes a "top" movie for rank purposes... nothing here for that to quantify...

Comment: @DRapp: Most probably I forgot that "small" detail :)

Comment: Tried it ... didn't populate de new table created :| Don't know what I'm missing here. If I remove the "WHERE star1>0" it populates the table but lefts unfilled the column id_actor.

Comment: Just figured out the problem (I think): On the new table I made id_actor an INT(4) and this query is picking the star1, star2 and star3 (varchars) from the table MOVIES and not replacing it for the ID of the actor present on the table ACTOR ... am I right ? I made printscreens of all my work so far please see them here [link]http://www.afonsogomes.com/help ! All help about this topic (and anything else you see fit that I do) is greatly appreciated! Only now I'm seing the full potencial of mySQL!

Comment: @afonso gomes, Yes, you are correct.  By us not knowing your structure column types, I guessed as integer as they are much easier for joins than character based... also, no ambiguity.  Primary and Foreign keys should be integer types, auto-increment anyway.  Prevents issues like customers with same name... don't query by name as you could get cross-results by different people... One table of customers... based on ID much like your movies and actors tables.

Comment: Yeah ... now I notice is much better to use integers :) but tell me something ... knowing how I have my tables what's the query to populate my MoviesActor db table ?

Comment: @Afonso Gomes, that's what the "insert into" from "select / union statement"... just make sure your data types are of same...  int vs char, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're joining with ACTOR using the NAME field which is a bit weird--ideally you'd want to join using ACTOR_ID, but anyway, the query below should do what you want under these assumptions:

```
select name, sex, image 
from actor
where name in 
(select star1 as star from movie
 union
 select star2 as star from movie
 union
 select star3 as star from movie)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems simple enough for me! :) I used your query but it only listed actors like: Morgan Freeman | M | 123.jpg ... I wanted also a count for the number of times his name appears on the SUM of star1 star2 and star3 ... is this possible mate?